# How to automatically make directory/file tree

Tags: bash, shell-script, mkdir

Let's say this is my shell script:

```
echo "testing" > ~/testing/dir/testfile.txt
mkdir ~/testing/testdir
```

However, there is no `testing` directory. I want my script to automatically create all the non-existent directories such as `~/testing/` annd `~/testing/dir/` without having to manually `mkdir` everyone of the,.

Is there a way to "force" it to `mkdir` the necessary directories?

Answer (score 2):

To make the whole tree,

`man mkdir`

> -p, --parents
>                no error if existing, make parent directories as needed

It creates all the parents needed

So you probably need: `mkdir -p ~/testing/testdir`